# My Old VGA display is not working on my laptop, All hardware are good, so, what's wrong?

Tags: display

I connected an old VGA port LCD display with a USB type c docker, it's working fine for a long time. Suddenly, one day it's not working. The Display does not light up. I have tried another laptop(same model) with the same docker, the display is okay, so the docker and display is fine. I have tried to connect my laptop with a HDMI projector, my laptop can project the screen, so my laptop is fine also. So, what's wrong? The setting of my laptop?

The last update: My USB-C docker dispaly works fine after a few days detachment, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test with a different USB-C port on the problem laptop.

If the projector worked (using VGA?) when connected to the problem laptop, then I recommend reinstalling or updating the vendor's software for your USB-C dock.

Comment: 1. USB-C dock got other ports (for mouse and keyboard),So I wonder maybe it's a software glitch or a pin hardware problem in my laptop.          2. it works normal now , after a few days I detach my laptop from USB-C dock.